# Getting Maven Build Error for spring-data-rest-webmvc 2.3.0.BUILD_SNAPSHOT

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-rest

When I run with Version 2.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT, I am getting below error since yesterday while runng mvn jetty:run. I tried deleting whole repository and clean install already. This error goes away on changing to 2.2.1.RELEASE.

```
    Gives Error -
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-rest-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>   

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.0.M1</version>
    </dependency>
```

ERROR : -

```
2015-01-13 14:59:45.730:WARN:oejuc.AbstractLifeCycle:main: FAILED org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyServer@1fc518f: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/projection/ProjectionFactory
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/projection/ProjectionFactory
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2688)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1962)
    at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.getAnnotatedMethods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:140)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:286)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:226)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:193)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:163)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:306)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:239)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:254)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:606)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:462)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:798)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:789)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1341)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.startWebapp(JettyWebAppContext.java:296)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1334)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:741)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.doStart(JettyWebAppContext.java:365)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyServer.doStart(JettyServer.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty(AbstractJettyMojo.java:534)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute(AbstractJettyMojo.java:357)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyRunMojo.execute(JettyRunMojo.java:167)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:133)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:108)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:76)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:361)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:157)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.data.projection.ProjectionFactory
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:259)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:235)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:227)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:450)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:403)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2688)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1962)
    at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.getAnnotatedMethods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:140)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:286)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:226)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:193)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:163)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:306)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:239)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:254)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:606)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:462)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:798)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:789)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1341)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.startWebapp(JettyWebAppContext.java:296)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1334)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:741)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.doStart(JettyWebAppContext.java:365)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyServer.doStart(JettyServer.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty(AbstractJettyMojo.java:534)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute(AbstractJettyMojo.java:357)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyRunMojo.execute(JettyRunMojo.java:167)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:133)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:108)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:76)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:361)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:157)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
[INFO] Jetty server exiting.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 17.701 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-01-13T14:59:45+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 24M/67M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:9.2.3.v20140905:run (default-cli) on project demo: Execution default-cli of goal org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:9.2.3.v20140905:run failed: A required class was missing while executing org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:9.2.3.v20140905:run: org/springframework/data/projection/ProjectionFactory
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:9.2.3.v20140905
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/C:/Users/USER1/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-maven-plugin/9.2.3.v20140905/jetty-maven-plugin-9.2.3.v20140905.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/C:/Users/USER1/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-inject-bean/2.1.1/sisu-inject-bean-2.1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/C:/Users/USER1/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-guice/2.9.4/sisu-guice-2.9.4-no_aop.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/C:/Users/USER1/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/2.0.6/plexus-utils-2.0.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/C:/Users/USER1/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/aether/aether-util/1.11/aether-util-1.11.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/C:/Users/USER1/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.14/plexus-interpolation-1.14.jar
[ERROR] urls[6] = file:/C:/Users/USER1/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-annotations/1.5.5/plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[7] = file:/C:/Users/USER1/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-sec-dispatcher/1.3/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[8] = file:/C:/Users/USER1/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-cipher/1.4/plexus-cipher-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[9] = file:/C:/Users/USER1/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-tools-api/3.1/maven-plugin-tools-api-3.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[10] = file:/C:/Users/USER1/.m2/repository/backport-util-concurrent/backport-util-concurrent/3.1/backport-util-concurrent-3.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[11] = file:/C:/Users/USER1/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-util/9.2.3.v20140905/jetty-util-9.2.3.v20140905.jar
[ERROR] urls[12] = file:/C:/Users/USER1/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-webapp/9.2.3.v20140905/jetty-webapp-9.2.3.v20140905.jar
[ERROR] urls[13] = file:/C:/Users/USER1/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-xml/9.2.3.v20140905/jetty-xml-9.2.3.v20140905.jar
[ERROR] urls[14] = file:/C:/Users/USER1/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-servlet/9.2.3.v20140905/jetty-servlet-9.2.3.v20140905.jar
[ERROR] urls[15] = file:/C:/Users/USER1/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-quickstart/9.2.3.v20140905/jetty-quickstart-9.2.3.v20140905.jar
[ERROR] urls[16] = file:/C:/Users/USER1/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-jaas/9.2.3.v20140905/jetty-jaas-9.2.3.v20140905.jar
[ERROR] urls[17] = file:/C:/Users/USER1/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-security/9.2.3.v20140905/jetty-security-9.2.3.v20140905.jar
[ERROR] urls[18] = file:/C:/Users/USER1/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-plus/9.2.3.v20140905/jetty-plus-9.2.3.v20140905.jar
[ERROR] urls[19] = file:/C:/Users/USER1/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-jndi/9.2.3.v20140905/jetty-jndi-9.2.3.v20140905.jar
[ERROR] urls[20] = file:/C:/Users/USER1/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-server/9.2.3.v20140905/jetty-server-9.2.3.v20140905.jar
[ERROR] urls[21] = file:/C:/Users/USER1/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/javax.servlet-api/3.1.0/javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[22] = file:/C:/Users/USER1/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-http/9.2.3.v20140905/jetty-http-9.2.3.v20140905.jar
[ERROR] urls[23] = file:/C:/Users/USER1/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-io/9.2.3.v20140905/jetty-io-9.2.3.v20140905.jar
[ERROR] urls[24] = file:/C:/Users/USER1/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-jmx/9.2.3.v20140905/jetty-jmx-9.2.3.v20140905.jar
[ERROR] urls[25] = file:/C:/Users/USER1/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-annotations/9.2.3.v20140905/jetty-annotations-9.2.3.v20140905.jar
[ERROR] urls[26] = file:/C:/Users/USER1/.m2/repository/javax/annotation/javax.annotation-api/1.2/javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[27] = file:/C:/Users/USER1/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm/5.0.1/asm-5.0.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[28] = file:/C:/Users/USER1/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm-commons/5.0.1/asm-commons-5.0.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[29] = file:/C:/Users/USER1/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm-tree/5.0.1/asm-tree-5.0.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[30] = file:/C:/Users/USER1/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/javax-websocket-server-impl/9.2.3.v20140905/javax-websocket-server-impl-9.2.3.v20140905.jar
[ERROR] urls[31] = file:/C:/Users/USER1/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/javax-websocket-client-impl/9.2.3.v20140905/javax-websocket-client-impl-9.2.3.v20140905.jar
[ERROR] urls[32] = file:/C:/Users/USER1/.m2/repository/javax/websocket/javax.websocket-api/1.0/javax.websocket-api-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[33] = file:/C:/Users/USER1/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/websocket-server/9.2.3.v20140905/websocket-server-9.2.3.v20140905.jar
[ERROR] urls[34] = file:/C:/Users/USER1/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/websocket-common/9.2.3.v20140905/websocket-common-9.2.3.v20140905.jar
[ERROR] urls[35] = file:/C:/Users/USER1/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/websocket-api/9.2.3.v20140905/websocket-api-9.2.3.v20140905.jar
[ERROR] urls[36] = file:/C:/Users/USER1/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/websocket-client/9.2.3.v20140905/websocket-client-9.2.3.v20140905.jar
[ERROR] urls[37] = file:/C:/Users/USER1/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/websocket-servlet/9.2.3.v20140905/websocket-servlet-9.2.3.v20140905.jar
[ERROR] urls[38] = file:/C:/Users/USER1/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/apache-jsp/9.2.3.v20140905/apache-jsp-9.2.3.v20140905.jar
[ERROR] urls[39] = file:/C:/Users/USER1/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/toolchain/jetty-schemas/3.1.M0/jetty-schemas-3.1.M0.jar
[ERROR] urls[40] = file:/C:/Users/USER1/.m2/repository/org/mortbay/jasper/apache-jsp/8.0.9.M3/apache-jsp-8.0.9.M3.jar
[ERROR] urls[41] = file:/C:/Users/USER1/.m2/repository/org/mortbay/jasper/apache-el/8.0.9.M3/apache-el-8.0.9.M3.jar
[ERROR] urls[42] = file:/C:/Users/USER1/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/orbit/org.eclipse.jdt.core/3.8.2.v20130121/org.eclipse.jdt.core-3.8.2.v20130121.jar
[ERROR] urls[43] = file:/C:/Users/USER1/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/apache-jstl/9.2.3.v20140905/apache-jstl-9.2.3.v20140905.jar
[ERROR] urls[44] = file:/C:/Users/USER1/.m2/repository/org/apache/taglibs/taglibs-standard-spec/1.2.1/taglibs-standard-spec-1.2.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[45] = file:/C:/Users/USER1/.m2/repository/org/apache/taglibs/taglibs-standard-impl/1.2.1/taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[46] = file:/C:/Users/USER1/.m2/repository/javax/transaction/javax.transaction-api/1.2/javax.transaction-api-1.2.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------: org.springframework.data.projection.ProjectionFactory
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException
```

Comment: It seems it has to do with JIRA - https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-618

Comment: I found the solution was to change Spring JPA 1.8.0.M1 to 1.8.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT

Comment: Why do you have multiple versions of the same artifact? <artifactId>spring-data-rest-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <artifactId>spring-data-rest-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>

Comment: @Stackee07 , that was just for example and am not using them together. I edited post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fixed now , I was mixing Snapshot and milestone releases as a result due to recent migration of Projections from spring-data-rest to spring-data-commons the conflict was arrising. Keeping both Spring -data-jpa and spring-data-rest-webmvc in Snapshot fixed it.